# Troll or skeptic?

Tags: discussion

One of us has been getting involved in lengthy and, some would say, pointless discussions on various questions. See, e.g., [59709](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59079/unique-representation-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-arithmetic), [58174](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58174/rule-for-multiplying-rational-numbers), and several others. Is this person raising serious mathematical issues, or is this person just a troll - and, if the latter, should something be done about it?

Comment: I've seen at least two people here give up on talking to him... my take-away on the conversations was that the person in question insists on his own interpretation and wonders why people don't see it his way.

Comment: The person you mention is entitled to his opinions and interpretations and it's fine with me when these are expressed in separate threads, as in the first question or in threads where such considerations are on-topic. What I'm having trouble with is when I think of poor user Sara asking an innocent question in the second post you mention. I hope she was wise enough to ignore the comment thread to her question that will have been confusing at best.

Comment: @Theo: Dear Theo, I agree completely; your comment summarizes the points I tried to convey in my answer below.  Best wishes,

Comment: @Matt: Dear Matt, thanks. I only saw your answer after I finished editing my comment and, indeed, we seem to agree fully. Best wishes,

Comment: I want to believe this person is acting obtuse rather than irreconcilably oblivious in the known threads, but he even blogged about one of my comments (linked by the Gerry in the OP here) and another question of his on magmas on his public and very old [xanga site](http://spoonwood.xanga.com/) (began 2002), so I don't think he's playing the contrarian simply to jerk our strings - I think he's engaged in what he deems as serious business. Since he has his own blog, he should definitely be made aware of when thread derailments don't belong on math.se if it comes up again in the future....

Comment: ....but as far as creating arguments and discussions that cause consternation, there isn't really a real problem: people will either ignore him or respond to him of their own free will, and beyond apparently ignoring many points repeatedly made to him, he has been conversing completely civilly. (And I also don't mean to imply all of his opinions expressed *aren't* serious business - I just believe a few issues he's taken up have been totally pedantic and semantics-based.)

Comment: Did somebody notify the person in question of this discussion? I haven't looked very hard but I didn't see a comment to that effect.

Comment: I just thought it might be worthwhile to link to the [edit suggested by Doug](http://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2104) for the second post (visible to 10k+ users). I'm not suggesting that the edit should have been approved, I would have rejected it as well.

Comment: @Theo: The edit suggestion is visible for everybody. And it is very enlightening, because Doug wanted to make it "rational numbers a, b, c, d", whereas Sara meant the rational numbers $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$.

Comment: @Hendrik: Ah, great, then I don't need to upload the screen shot I just made.

Comment: @Gerry Perhaps the title should be "Troll, skeptic or **philosopher**". As DS writes on his [blog](http://dougspoonwood.blogspot.com/) " I graduated from Bowling Green in 2002 with a degree in Philosophy". You've probably encountered some of the many analogous posts by philosophers over the years on sci.math (cont'd)

Comment: I don't believe we have established any consensus on how to deal with meta-level topics such as philosophy of mathematics. But I think we should be very careful not to make any decision while under the influence of not the most interesting philosophical discussions. There are many mathematical philosophers whose expositions would be of interest to a large segment of the mainstream mathematics community, including our main site.

Comment: @Bill: sure. I think it is absurd to call the inane disquisition about the fact that $2\cdot(3\cdot 5)$ and  $(2\cdot 3)\cdot 5$ are not the same string of pencil marks on a page and its putative relationship to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, philosophy of mathematics!

Comment: @Mar That's but one of many matters DS has discussed here. Whether or not you consider those interesting philosophical points is something you should take up with DS, not I. There do exist mathematical philosophers who have written interesting papers on semiotics of mathematics and related matters.

Comment: @Mariano 2⋅(3⋅5) and (2⋅3)⋅5 *evaluate* to the same number.  Speaking more precisely, the first expression means "the application of the multiplication function at 2 and the number which gets obtained via the application of the multiplication function at (3, 5)", and the second "the application of the multiplication function where the first number gets obtained via the application of the multiplication function at (2, 3) and the number 2".  That both applications *evaluate* to the same number is not in question.  They are not, however, the same application.  At least, that's what I'd say.

Comment: @Mariano In other words, it's not just that they aren't the same strings.  +23, and 23+ have the same meaning, but I don't regard as the same strings.  But, 2⋅(3⋅5) and (2⋅3)⋅5 do not have the same meaning in terms of the application of the multiplication function.  They only have the same meaning in terms of their evaluation.

Comment: @Doug: In mathematics one proves, or assumes, conditions which allow him to consider different strings as if they are the same. In the above case, associativity. That is, if the theory *proves* $\times(\times(x,y),z)=\times (x,\times(y,z))$ then we can assume that $\times(\times(x,y),z)=\times(x,\times(y,z))$ since the interpretation is the same.

Comment: @Asaf There exists a hidden condition there, which basically goes either "multiplication" is the only operation on the set, or all expressions "x", "y", and "z" come as clear in the first place.  For example, consider two arbitrary associative operations "!" and "@".  Well, a!b!c@d is simply not unambiguous, and association doesn't suffice to prove that (a!(b!(c@d)))=(a!((b!c)@d)).  The theory could prove association, but you still can't regard even a!b!c@d as the same string as even a!b!c@d in the theory, since a!b!c@d is not clear in the theory.  This issue only pops up in infix notation.

Comment: @Doug: Dear Doug, I think most mathematicians regard $xyz$ (multiplication of three numbers) as a ternary operation; at least I do.  It is defined as either $(xy)z$ or $x(yz)$ --- as you know, these give the same answer.   Regards,

Comment: @Matt E Thanks for that.

Answer (score 32):

I am more concerned by the behaviour in the second-linked post than in the first. In the second linked post (the one about multiplying rational numbers), this person's comments led to a comment thread filled with more-or-less off-topic nonsense, which is surely unpleasant and distracting for the OP, and for others browsing the site.  (Indeed, it damages the credibility of the site when someone asking about multiplying rational numbers gets a slew of nonsense comments, rather than simple-and-to-the-point comments and answers.)

The first linked post is a different case, since it was asked by the person in question, and other users of the site are free to ignore it if they want to, or to vote it down (as they in fact did).

Would it be too heavy-handed for the moderators to request that this person not use the comment threads in other people's questions as a soap-box?

Comment: "moderators to request that this person not use the comment threads in other people's questions as a soap-box?" - yes, please, count me in with this request.

Comment: Would it appropriate for one of us to clear the comment thread? We can copy it over if people want to see the history, but in the name of keeping it clean for actual site *usage*, we do have the option. I'm aware of some issues that have been had in the past with deletions, so even though your description, to me, sounds like it warrants deletion, I figure it'd be wise to check in, first.

Comment: @Grace Please let OUR moderators decide. Evaluating such matters often requires specific knowledge of the mathematical matters at issue. Moroever, we have our own conventions here that may be quite different from SO or other SE sites. There's been a lot of confusion here recently on related issues, e.g. above and [here,](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58667) so the discussion there may prove enlightening to some readers, even if it goes beyond the OP's concerns. It's only a dozen comments, some with useful pedagogical value. There are many comment threads here that are *much* worse.

Comment: @bill I agree that 12 comments isn't necessarily a huge problem, but I would be deeply concerned if a particular user kept engaging people on this site in the same sort of pointless-ish debates that are at best tangential. Get enough of that and you will start driving away your best users.

Answer (score 16):

Doug is very difficult to talk to, but I can't make up my mind whether he's actually done anything *wrong* (as opposed to simply misguided). I am convinced he is not a troll. I would recommend that anyone who doesn't want to get involved just ignore everything he says.

Comment: +1 I agree he is not a troll. I haven't yet figured out why he places so much emphasis on matters that most of us deem trivial. These matters are important for presenting *formal* proofs to automated theorem provers, but not for informal proofs presented to mathematical peers. So perhaps he's working on automated theorem proving and his questions represent his struggles attempting to formalize some of the math he's learned. Speaking from experience, this can be *extremely* difficult if one does not have the appropriate mathematical background - which requires very diverse skills.

Comment: @Bill: based on what I've read I think he just equates mathematics with formal mathematics.

Comment: Indeed. Above I was speculating on possible motives why that might be so. Browsing his numerous blogs may yield further insight.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, the problem here is that some people do not try hard enough to *understand the question* and sometimes *use their answers/comments to express their opinions* in place of trying to answer the question that has been asked, independent of the intention of the person asking the question.

Unless explicitly mentioned otherwise, it is common practice in mathematics to assume that we are talking in the language of classical mathematicians (who are usually not interested in philosophical discussions), we write informal arguments with enough details that the other person can complete by themselves, but not too much details (which is a skill/art by itself).

Say I ask a question about how to prove [AC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) from [Zorn lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma). If someone comments on my question by saying that [AC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) can be problematic in constructive mathematics he/she might be saying something **correct**, but that is **irrelevant** to what I am asking! Understanding questions (what is being asked? what is the context? what is the right level of detail? ...) is an important part of answering questions.

Comment: Is this meant to apply to DS's comments/answers or, rather, to comments by others to DS's questions, or is it meant to apply universally? Without knowing which it is difficult to interpret what the votes mean (currently +4,-0).

Comment: @Bill, I am trying to explain the underlining problem, I think it does apply to some of DS's comments/answers but my point is more general.

Comment: And it also applies to many of the comments by others to DS's questions.

Comment: @Bill, it can, if his intention is to ask a question about philosophy of mathematics and someone comments by saying that most mathematicians accept some classical mathematics assumption, then that comment is not relevant to the question (although it is probably correct). ps: I should add that I don't think this applies to the first question linked above in my opinion, because the questions is asking about the meaning of a classical mathematical result.

Comment: Right. My main point was to *explicitly* emphasize that because your answer refers to a general issue, the votes that it receives cannot be interpreted as community feedback on DS's specific behavior. Rather they can only be interpreted as applying to the general issue that you raise.

Comment: Kaveh, that the issue arises does also apply to comments by others to my questions.  As a good case-in-point see this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60259/what-does-it-mean-exactly-to-claim-logical-theorems-axioms-independent  Carl's answer got upvoted, but it was irrelevant.  I asked about independence of logical theorems (axioms), and Carl responded by talking about rules of inference!  I decided to ignore that since he said something I found interesting, but the question was clearly misunderstood since rules of inference are metalogical, and theorems (axioms) are logical.

Comment: @Doug, I think the presumption here is that one is asking a question *in* mathematics not *about* it, so if you want philosophical answers you should better be more specific about the kind of answers you are interested in. In that question you are asking what independence means (by people who use the word i.e. mathematicians/logicians), and therefore Carl's answer is completely relevant IMO and I am one of the users who has up-voted it.

Comment: @Kaveh I asked about independence of axioms.  In other words, the independence of a particular axiom from a set of axioms. All axioms fall under the same category.  Carl answered "We could say that A is independent of a set of axioms B if A is not an admissible rule over B, or if A is not a derivable rule over B."  Now, A refers to a rule.  Thus, his response talks about the independence of *the rule* A from *the set of axioms* B.  They don't happen in the same category.  If they do, the distinction between the object language and metalanguage is obliterated.  In logic this does not happen.

Comment: @Doug, FYI, an axiom is a special case of a rule. In any case, this is not relevant to my post here. If you have a problem with his answer comment on his answer not here.

Comment: @Kaveh An axiom basically comes as a formula of a certain kind.  A rule of inference is not a formula.  For any axiom x you can write "|- x", and no axiom can have anything to the left of the turnstile.  On the other hand rules of inference can have things to the left of the turnstile.  Axioms are not special cases of rules.

Comment: @Doug, you have the bad habit of discussing issues in the wrong places. As I said this is not relevant to my post above. If you have a question ask it on the main site, as I said this is not the place for it. (and no! you are wrong. If you want to know why you are wrong ask a question on the main site and I will answer it.)

Answer (score 4):

So far, the volume seems small, so I don't see it as a problem.  Those who want to ignore these posts will do so, others will answer.  I suspect the odds of OP satisfaction are low, and the population that ignore these posts will increase.  Unless the volume gets high enough to be a problem I would ignore it.

Comment: Any reason why you chose to reopen this discussion 2 months after the rest of us lost interest?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No, I forget why it came up.  I thought I posted this longer ago than last night, don't know why it is here now.

Comment: "About four years ago I---no, it was yesterday..." -Steven Wright

Comment: "I suspect the odds of OP satisfaction are low, and the population that ignore these posts will increase."  If you had posted this long ago, it definitely has turned out false in the case of post 59709.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't aware of this thread until now (did I miss someone informing me of it?).  If the following isn't too self-indulgent, I'll try and explain why I place emphasis on matters others deem trivial.

I remember once reading Richard Feynman talking about some physics paper he wrote up and how his colleague responded to it.  It contained a bunch of difficult mathematics to make some point about the physical world.  His colleague looked at the paper and basically said "How does anyone know that isn't a bunch of "junk"?"... except the exact word wasn't "junk", of course.  Feynman decided he would do better to stick to the simpler mathematics in his papers after that.

Somewhat similarly, if I look at some mathematical piece of writing which purports to have a proof or other mathematical reasoning, how do I know that the argument given isn't a bunch of junk?  I know some people might refer to the authority of "the mathematical community" for this, but it still comes as possible that the entire community has gotten mislead in some way (this is NOT a claim that this is happening).  As I understand it, in the course of mathematical history "false proofs" have gotten accepted by "the mathematical community", as at least I feel sure some of Euclid's "false proofs" got accepted by "the mathematical community" of a time long ago.  I realize some other might respond to my query by saying "well a proof is just meant to be intuitively convincing."  Well, my experience and observation of others informs that it at least seems possible that, in principle, one can feel convinced of *absolutely anything*.  If that holds, and proofs *just* need to come as convincing, then it actually comes as fair to say that mathematical proofs and mathematical reasoning in general qualifies as a bunch of junk.

The only way I've ever seen to resolve that problem comes as to make it so that proofs in mathematics don't fall into such difficulties comes as to make sure that a proof, or assertion, can get formalized.  And the only definition of proof that I think actually works comes as that a proof is either a formalized statement, or can get precisiated into a formalized statement.  I don't mean to assert that it always comes as necessary or desireable to formalize mathematical proofs and assertions, and no I don't equate mathematics with formal mathematics exactly.  But, if there ever exists any doubt that a proof can get formalized, then it should get formalized.  Of course that depends on which logic one takes for granted also, but any formalization makes it clear, I think, that *if* the logical system gets taken for granted, the rest will follow.  At present, that's the only way I can see to resolve this problem.

I also will add that many people take mathematics as having classical logic in the background, and I generally make comments and answers trying to assume that background.  This has significance, as to paraphrase Lukasiewicz, classical logic is not a heap of stones.  If the very, very slightest error exists in some claim made in the context of classical logic, the claim ends up *completely* false, and the structure trying to get built completely collapses.  The same holds for mathematics where we have classical logic in the background.  Consequently, even very, very trivial matters need to get looked at, or in other words, nothing is trivial.  Of course, though, if you don't have classical logic in the background and say have a logical system that allows for minor contradictions, this sort of issue doesn't arise.

And that's my take.  I feel sure many will disagree.  If this answer isn't appropriate, I will delete it.  And I have no clue if that all makes me into a "skeptic", a "troll", or "philosopher", because I don't know what sort of meaning you want to imbue to those terms, and I do think there exist different, valid, not necessarily consistent, ways to think about those terms.

Comment: Formalization solves nothing - how is your thought process when reading a "formal" proof any more trustworthy than your thought process when reading a natural language proof? Perhaps you have a brain tumor that causes every 10000th statement you read to appear true to you, regardless of it's correct truth value? Even *computerized* formalization solves nothing; perhaps your automatic theorem checker has a bug in it. As you say, one can feel convinced of *absolutely anything*, including that one has correctly checked a formal proof.

Comment: You may find the [discussion on this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29104/why-are-proofs-so-valuable-although-we-do-not-know-that-our-axiom-system-is-cons) helpful. In particular, I like Tom Goodwillie's comment that "If you're looking for utter certainty, then even mathematics is not entirely the right field", and of course Terry Tao's answer that "ultimately, mathematicians are not really after proofs, despite appearances; they are after understanding."

Comment: Terry Tao's [blog post on the pre-rigorous, rigorous, and post-rigorous](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/there%E2%80%99s-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/) stages of one's mathematical education is also relevant here: "It is of course vitally important that you know how to think rigorously, as this gives you the discipline to avoid many common errors and purge many misconceptions. Unfortunately, this has the unintended consequence that “fuzzier” or “intuitive” thinking

Comment: (such as heuristic reasoning, judicious extrapolation from examples, or analogies with other contexts such as physics) gets deprecated as “non-rigorous”. All too often, one ends up discarding one’s initial intuition and is only able to process mathematics at a formal level, thus getting stalled at the second stage of one’s mathematical education." (You happen to be experiencing this stalling.) "The ideal state to reach is when every heuristic argument naturally suggests its rigorous counterpart, and vice versa."

Comment: @Zev The thought process isn't necessarily more trustworthy.  Yes, one can incorrectly feel that one has correctly checked a formal proof.  So, if there exists any doubt about such a check as correctly done, one can re-check the proof again to see that it *yields* the conclusion.  Since the formal proof has stable symbols independent of the meanings which we assign to them (or at least considerations of meaning get pushed near to 0), the proof can get checked until the symbols degrade.  Though formalization might not solve everything as you point it, this in no way implies it solves nothing.

Comment: *What if you never think to doubt a particular faulty check? What if every double-check you run suffers from the same error, indefinitely?* The point that formalization lets us discard the meanings of our symbols, while correct, is irrelevant. You're under the mistaken impression that mathematics somehow enables us to gain absolute knowledge. You experience everything, whether it be  page after page of symbols, or a computer readout of an automatic check, through your untrustworthy senses.

Comment: Being a philosophy student, I'm sure you're familiar with [skepticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_skepticism)?

Comment: In my opinion, formalization, or its possibility, makes it possible to solve more of the concerns like the above than any appeal to "intuition" or "the mathematical community".  Yes, neither mathematics nor logic will not give you utter certainty.  However, this does not imply that if things get understood properly that rigor will not give you *more* certainty than any other method in general.  I'm really not sure that Lakatos's categorization (Tao's stages, I think, originate from Lakatos) works all that well.  Additionally, I doubt that anyone ever gets completely comfortable with rigor.

Comment: @Zev If every double-check you run suffers the same error, then you double-check the double-checking procedure.  I do not believe that mathematics allows us to gain absolute knowledge.  Of course I experience everything through potentially imperfect senses.  However, this does not mean that the grade of certainty does not go up when performing more checks, and more checks upon checks.  It also comes as possible that mathematics and especially formal logic have a *higher* grade of certainty than anything else, especially since certainty like most other things *are* a matter of degree.

Comment: @Zev In short, it seems like you've tried to counter-argue to my position via throwing it into a classical logic context.  The problem comes as that it isn't in such a context, and you immediately create a straw-man by doing so.  Even when I write something like "The only way I've ever seen to resolve that problem comes as to make it so that proofs in mathematics don't fall into such difficulties comes as to make sure that a proof, or assertion, can get formalized."  My real position has qualifiers like "significantly", "major", "very", etc.  You can't use all-or-none thinking to refute these.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood your position, I didn't intend to make a straw man argument. At any rate, I'm glad that you agree that there is no certainty, even with "formal" proofs. But, if you were to ask a mathematician which would convince them more of a statement's validity, a natural language proof or a computer printout claiming to verify some formalized version of the statement, I think that a significant proportion, even most, would choose the natural language proof.

Comment: Two things: 1. I feel bad that you weren't notified and had to find out about this thread by accident. I apologize for not notifying you. 2. I don't want to be dragged into this debate, but I wanted to point you to Bettina Heintz's *[Die Innenwelt der Mathematik](http://books.google.com/books?id=Tjzlm0B9fUgC)* (hoping you read German) which I found very interesting. I'm sure you're aware of Lakatos's [Ph.D. thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_and_Refutations). Both these books are not exactly addressing the issues here, but are closely related, in my opinion.

Comment: You may also want to consider Paul Siegel's comment from the MO question: "I don't worry about such things for the same reason that I still walk to work every day even though I could get hit by a car at any minute. If I spend the rest of my life trying to convince myself that what I think is a proof really is a proof and one day I actually succeed, then I will just wish I had spent all that time thinking about geometry instead." It would take far too much effort to formalize their work for most mathematicians (e.g., all mathematicians who don't work on formalization) to bother -

Comment: after all, there's the actual mathematics to think about. As a part of a mathematician's training, they learn how to take any given  heuristic argument and write down its rigorous counterpart (to use Tao's terms), and vice versa. This lets them reason using a mix of both methods that produces a (more or less) ideal combination of *minimizing errors* and *maximizing theorems/ideas*. It is absolutely true: by not formalizing everything we have the slightest doubt about, we introduce the possibility of error.

Comment: But the value of the mathematics we've done in the meantime (the vast majority of it having no fault whatsoever) outweighs this possibility.

Comment: @Doug: I think I should leave it at that, for now. With Theo, I would also like to express my apologies for your not being notified of this thread, it may have been a case of everyone assuming that someone else had done so. While most people (including me) would argue about the relevance of your concerns to the actual practice of mathematics, I consider it important that your concerns are addressed, as this is key to getting "unstalled". I hope that what I've said helped in some small amount. Hopefully others will chime in with their thoughts and opinions about the practice of mathematics.

Comment: @Zev Re: your first comment that "formalization solves nothing". Do you *really* think that the rigorization of calculus and, more recently, the formalization of intuitive Italian geometry by modern algebraic geometry "solved nothing"?

Comment: @Bill: You misunderstand - I mean that when we already have rigorous foundations, writing proofs using little or no natural language and convoluted strings of logical symbols (or using the silly [two-column format](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/Math/Geometry_obj/two_column_proof.htm)) solves nothing. Obviously, the process of developing rigorous foundations where there were none (e.g. calculus, Euclidean geometry, Italian school algebraic geometry) is an essential part of the development of mathematics.

Comment: @Zev There may exist more to it than that.  When I've read rigorous proofs, it seems that more unexpected connections pop up than an informal proof helps us to realize.  As perhaps too simple of an example, if you wish to show that logical conjunction in 2-valued propositional logic commutes, you could just point out the truth table and point out the completeness theorem. But, if you formally prove it, once you realize what you've done, you'll have connected it to some valid inference rules, and that immediately translates into a proof for *any* propositional system with those inference rules.

Comment: @Zev Some old-school Italian geometers would consider algebraic formalizations of their proofs to be "convoluted strings of symbols" - devoid of geometric intuition. One could say the same about mechanical proofs spit out by Grobner basis algorithms.

Comment: @Zev Edit: where those valid inference rules used in the proof, and the axioms used in the proof apply.

Comment: @Bill: I certainly don't claim to understand modern algebraic geometry, but I have enough of a sense of it to say that the geometric intuition simply takes a bit more time to see; if the Italian geometers had time to get training in the newer theory, I am sure they would come around. It would be their failure if they ignored [demonstrable errors](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19420) simply because they didn't see the intuition right away.

Comment: To quote Lockhart (who is a bit hyperbolic, but makes excellent points), "Rigorous formal proof only becomes important when there is a crisis - when you discover that your imaginary objects behave in a counterintuitive way; when there is a paradox of some kind." There was such a crisis, and modern algebraic geometry was developed as a result. Perhaps there will be future crises. But in the meantime, "A proof should be an epiphany from the Gods, not a coded message from the Pentagon. This is what comes from a misplaced sense of logical rigor: ugliness."

Comment: (in reference to a two-column geometry proof): "The spirit of the argument has been buried under a heap of confusing formalism. No mathematician works this way. No mathematician has ever worked this way. This is a complete and utter misunderstanding of the mathematical enterprise. Mathematics is not about erecting barriers between ourselves and our intuition, and making simple things complicated. Mathematics is about removing obstacles to our intuition, and keeping simple things simple." This is the essence of my, and I think most others', criticism of Doug's approach to mathematics.

Comment: @Zev I don't necessarily disagree with you. Rather, I just wanted to point out that one has to be careful about making such very general statements since they could easily be misinterpreted by those who are not experienced mathematicians.

Comment: @Bill: Ah, I see what you mean. I shall indeed be more careful in situations like these in the future.

Comment: @Doug: On the value of purely syntactic proofs in classical propositional logic: I think one has to first appreciate the value of non-classical propositional logics, and this is probably the hard part for most people. For instance, the main reason why *I* am interested in intuitionistic logic is because of its connections to constructive mathematics and theoretical computer science. And before I knew much about *that* I don't think I appreciated the autonomy of syntax in logic very well.

Comment: @Zhen I think that's one way to see their value for sure, and perhaps most common. However, I think one might also see their value via comparing different formulations of classical propositional logic. As I'm sure you know, the value of formal proofs can get seen to emerge from multivalued, and infinite valued logics, as well as two-valued logics which aren't functionally complete, e. g. the pure implicational and equivalential calculi, and many other sub-systems can in principle get constructed. I know it also took me a while to understand why truth-valued calculations weren't used that much.

Answer (score -8):

Edit: I do agree that the lengthy comment thread at [Sara's question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58174/rule-for-multiplying-rational-numbers) is not really relevant to that question.

However, let me point out that Doug really has a *very good* point in his first comment to Sara's question (maybe without realizing the point himself ...). The thing is that of course one has to justify $b^{-1}\cdot d^{-1}=(b\cdot d)^{-1}$.  For this one first of all wants that $b\cdot d \ne 0$ if $b\ne0$ and $d\ne0$, and this does *not* follow from commutativity and associativity alone;  you need *distributivity*.

Now I do agree that he could have made this clear himself, and I'm not even sure that this really *was* the point he wanted to make. But I somehow can understand his line of communication. In one of the later comments he wrote

> Look, write out the proof for b^(-1)*d^(-1)=(b*d)^(-1) with a proof analysis citing every step along the way.

Well, I did, and came to the conclusion that you need distributivity unless you're willing to allow that $b\cdot d=0$ in $(b\cdot d)^{-1}$.

Comment: So, first you declare that Doug has a very good point, then you explain what the very good point is, and finally you state that you are not sure that the point you explained really is Doug's point. That's interesting... More to the point (if I may say), distributivity as I know it involves **two** binary operations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property but here I see only one. You might wish to explain.

Comment: (Re: And this does not follow from commutativity and associativity alone!) Well, the statement in question is true in any monoid (where it doesn't even make sence to talk about distributivity). The point is, you don't need to _use_ that $b\cdot d$ has inverse, you _prove_ it (showing that $b^{-1}\cdot d^{-1}$ is such inverse).

Comment: @Grigory: Yes, it follows that $b\cdot d$ has an inverse, but the point is still that you want $b\cdot d\ne0$, and this does _not_ follow from commutativity and associativity alone. I've edited my answer accordingly; it was indeed misleading.

Comment: @Didier: You have a point there `:-)` (in your first sentence). I see the second operation when I write $0$, which is the neutral element of _addition_.

Comment: @Grigory: Then please prove that $0$ has no inverse.

Comment: @Hendrik Sorry, you're right, one needs distributivity to show that $b\cdot d\ne0$. But the point is, it's not relevant to Sara's question, is it?

Comment: @Hendrik, right. So what is bothering you is that the statement "if neither b nor d is zero then bd is not zero either" is unproved? But since one **exhibits** an inverse of bd (under the assumption that neither b nor d is zero), this step is as rigorous as can be, no? (Grigori's point, in fact.) And really, the only assumption used here is that one is in a group where b and d both have an inverse and the conclusion is that bd has an inverse as well (which is how I thought about the matter and explains that I did not see why the neutral element of the addition was needed at all).

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the prototypical [integral domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain). This is for most purposes [a given](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Algebraic_properties) in elementary arithmetic. Observe Doug's issue in the thread was basically that the existence of an identity and inverses were never explicitly posited, even though as Gerry pointed these two assumptions are as evident as they need be for Sarah and non-pedants simply by the form of the setup. In the end, insistence on excessive levels of formality can be superfluous or even counterproductive to learning.

Comment: @Didier: Well, you have a point again `:-)`, but I'm being completely serious with my trouble about this. I taught the axioms of the real numbers in an Analysis 1 course recently, and in the field axioms it says that every number $x\ne0$ has an inverse, denoted $x^{-1}$. (It does not say that 0 does _not_ have an inverse.) Then I said that $x^{-1}y^{-1}$ is an inverse of $xy$, but I didn't write it as $(xy)^{-1}$ since I didn't have $xy\ne0$ yet, and the notation $0^{-1}$ is undefined. This is clearly somewhat pedantic, but I think it is an important piece of pedantry.

Comment: @Grigory: I do agree that the comment thread at Sara's question is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @Henrik: If you *demonstrate* $b\cdot d$ has an inverse given $b,d\ne0$ (plus commutativity and associativity), there's no need to assume $b\cdot d\ne0$, right?

Comment: @anon: You didn't get my point. I don't write $(xy)^{-1}$ because this might still be $0^{-1}$, which I don't want to write. (I forgot to mention in my previous comment that at that point in my lecture I had all the field axioms but the axiom of distributivity. I found it very important to point out that without this axiom one can't prove that $0$ doesn't have an inverse.)

Comment: Hendrik, how can it possibly be the case that $xy=0$ if the inverse of $xy$ demonstrably exists? You're making no sense. You don't even need to explicitly write $(xy)^{-1}$ before you show $xy$ has an inverse anyway, so there's no issue here.

Comment: @Grigory: I forgot to submit my edit; now it's there.

Comment: @Hendrik, thanks for your answer. You explained your point, which is that the assertion "b not zero and d not zero implies bd not zero" requires a proof, and I do not agree with this point but these things just happen.

Comment: @Didier: What do you mean by "I do not agree with this point"? Do you mean that "b not zero and d not zero implies bd not zero" _doesn't_ require a proof? Then I stymied. Or do you mean that it does require a proof, but that this isn't so important here? Then it's "these things just happen" for me, too.

Comment: @anon: Maybe you didn't follow my discussion with Grigory here. I can only ask you the same thing as I asked Grigory: please prove that $0$ has no inverse. You won't succeed with commutativity and associativity alone.

Comment: @Hendrik: Whatever suits you best. *These things just happen* also means that at this point I feel like having made every meaningful point I could make (if any) and that, as a consequence, I intend to leave the discussion.

Comment: @Didier: Hmm, I'm somewhat disappointed by your answer. I really understand if you say the point I'm trying to make is not important for you, but if you imply that some things might not need proofs, then I'm at a loss here. Isn't math all about proofs? (Or is "b not zero and d not zero implies bd not zero" an _axiom_ for you?)

Comment: Hendrik: The original question this all sprang from was decidedly *not* at the level of analysis, it was just basic algebra, where (as I already said above) no zero divisors *is* taken as a given, and rightly so for pedagogical reasons. It's true I likely stretched the discussion into formalism with my first comment over at the thread, but I certainly did not take the torch this far. As for the present discussion, while it's true I was not aware of my own assumption that $0$ has no inverse, I'm *still* curious as to how such an inverse would invalidate the proof of $b^{-1}d^{-1}=(bd)^{-1}$?

Comment: @Hen 1 There's no reason to jump through hoops to avoid mention of $0^{-1}$. For if $0$ is invertible in R then $1 = 0\:r = 0$, a contradiction if R $\ne$ {$0$} (recall that $1\ne0$ by definition in a field or domain). But if R = {$0$} then $r = 0^{-1} = 0$. No problem. When R $\ne$ {$0$} that is a valid way to conclude a proof by contradiction. If you restrict your definition of inverse to nonzero elements then you prevent such proofs. That was my key point in this [recent question](http://bit.ly/paHI7n) on a proof in Rudin - see my comments to Asaf in my answer. Cont'd in Hen 2 below.

Comment: @Hen 2 It's more natural to use the unrestricted (*universal*) definition of an inverse, i.e. in *any* commutative ring R if $rs = 1$ then $r^{-1} := s$. That is well-defined since inverses are unique $s = s(rs') = (sr)s' = s'$. As above, it works fine if $r=0$, when, necessarily R = {$0$}. Introducing (unecessary) exceptions in definitions only complicates the application of such definitions in proofs (it may causes extra branching and possible combinatorial explosion in proofs).

Comment: @Hen To say that a proof about rings depends on the distributive law is not saying much. For any proof that does not use the distributive law is either a proof about a ring's additive group or multiplicative monoid. The two have no connection whatsoever without the distributive law. Thus any proof not using the distributive law is really a proof about commutative groups or monoids.

Comment: @anon This is the same issue that I discussed in the recent thread on Rudin's proof that fields have no zero-divisors, see my comments "@Hen 1" and "@Hen 2" above.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for your comments. Above you've used $0r=0$, which again requires distributivity, or am I mistaken? It seems that I didn't present my case well, but I still have the same trouble with the claim that commutativity and associativity alone suffice. Yes, they do if you're willing to allow for an inverse of $0$, but personally I don't like this.

Comment: @anon: OK, now I see where some of the misunderstanding comes from. To me it's not so clear on which level this question was asked. More importantly, I have a background of teaching at German universities, where in math lectures you usually won't take _anything_ as a given. (You probably won't prove every single detail, but I strive to point that out whenever it happens.)

Comment: @anon: As for how such an inverse would invalidate the proof of $b^{-1}d^{-1}=(bd)^{-1}$, I wrote this already above. It indeed _doesn't_ invalidate the proof (and my first version of this answer was thus in a bad shape), it's just a question of whether you're willing to write down something that might be $0^{-1}$. I'm not willing to do that since I define $a^{-1}$ only for $a\ne0$.

Comment: @Bill: Sorry for bugging you. I'd really like to know what you say about "you've used $0r=0$, which again requires distributivity, or am I mistaken?" My whole case here (which I didn't present well, it appears) is about the fact that with commutativity and associativity alone you can't prove that $0$ is not invertible.

Comment: @Hen 4 Yes, to prove that $0$ is absorbing, i.e. $0\:x = 0$, does require the distributive law when one is using ring axioms such that it is the only law connecting the additive and multiplicative structure. Without distributivity one can put any monoid structure on an abelian group and satisfy the other ring axioms. E.g. on an abelian group $\ne 0$ define multiplication as addition:  $x\:y = x+y,\ 1 = 0\:.\:$ Then $0\:x = 0 + x = x \ne 0\:$ for $\rm\:x\ne 0\:,\:$ i.e. a neutral element is absorbing only in a trivial monoid. Cont'd in Hen 5 below.

Comment: @Hen 5 Hence if one deletes the distributive law from the ring axioms, then nothing is left to connect the additive and multiplicative structures; the structure degenerates to a separate abelian group and monoid structure on a set. In particular the additive neutral element $0$ need not have any special multiplicative properties such as being absorbing. But this has nothing to do with rings, because one never drops the distributive law - only possibly the commutative or associative laws. $0\:x = 0$ is an *essential* property of rings - whether it is an axiom or derived from other axioms.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for your answer and for the confirmation. You put it in much better words than I did ("if one deletes the distributive law from the ring axioms, then nothing is left to connect the additive and multiplicative structures"; this is what I meant and should have written). I'm still not sure what anon and Didier meant to say in this comment thread, but I think I'm done with this now and will probably delete my answer soon. It appears that I didn't manage to convey my thoughts and that the answer wasn't well received (my point probably being both minor and pedantic to most?).

Comment: @Hen Please don't delete the answer since I'd like to reference my comments here when I revise my other answers to clarify these and related matters.

Comment: @Bill 1: Won't you be able to still see the comments after deletion of the answer? By the way, I had a look at [that Rudin question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/58667) now, and I must say that I agree with the people there who say that one mustn't write $\frac{xy}{xy}$. At the very least one _shouldn't_ write it (and Rudin doesn't). But I'm impressed at how you got it right when writing "The OP could be attempting to understand a textbook proof ..."!

Comment: @Bill 2: I don't like Rudin's proof, actually. I'd say: 1st case: $x=0$, then we're done. 2nd case: $x\ne0$, then $y=\frac{xy}{x}=0$ by (a).

Comment: @Hen 6 Re: 1. If you delete the question then no one $< 10k$ can see the comments. They are very valuable. Re: Rudin. As I explained, it *is* rigorous to write $\ 1 = 0/0 = 0\:0^{-1} = 0\ $ in the $0$ ring (the context of Rudin's proof). But presenting this proof (or Rudin's) is ill-advised for an intro Analysis course because it invites confusion - as we've seen. I hope to explain these matters at length in my answer when some time frees up. This will probably result in some upvotes here. I just upvoted since the downvotes are *undeserved*. Alas, there is much confusion on such matters.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks a lot for the consolation. (Yeah, I know that you need 10k rep to see deleted answers, but I was wondering since you have a lot more rep. But I'll leave the answer if you think it's worth it.) And yes, in the 0 ring I fully agree that writing $1=0/0=0$ is just fine.

Comment: Though I didn't have distributivity in mind, I think this a very informative discussion, so I'd classify this answer as a good one (and I've upvoted it).  Especially the part where Bill clearly demonstrates, in my opinion, that 0 can have an inverse in an exceptional case.